# Question/Help about community-supprot services provided by Ubuntu

Tags: community, support

The following community support services provided by Ubuntu:-

- [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/)
- [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/)
- [Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/)

I want to get information for Which & When should I use from above?

In other words, When to use/choose between them?

What is different-way in community-support provided by them? **[Finding Help in different way]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://community.ubuntu.com/help-information/finding-help/support/:

- Askubuntu

  > Ask Ubuntu
  >
  > http://askubuntu.com
  >
  > This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for Ubuntu
  >   users and developers. If you’re looking to ask questions on how to use
  >   your Ubuntu computer, then this is the place to go. Instead of posting
  >   like a mailing list or forum, this site works by you repeatedly
  >   editing your question with what you’ve learned about your problem, and
  >   then users can rate the quality of the questions and answers by
  >   voting. If you’re interested in learning how the site works, check out
  >   this guide.

  **Visit:** [Community Support](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/support/ask-ubuntu/)

- Launchpad Answers

  > Technical answers system
  >
  > Add a support-related question to the search-field on Launchpad. Keep
  >   your query active until a community member offers the answer you need.
  >   You can also search the complete history of questions and answers.
  >   This site supports multiple-languages.

  **Visit:** [Community Support](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/support/launchpad-answers/)

- Ubuntuforums

  > Web forums
  >
  > If you prefer to use web forums rather than mailing lists, especially
  >   for support-related issues, you can use or search the Ubuntu forums.
  >   There are also local language forums available.

  **Visit** [Community Support](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/support/ubuntu-forums/)

- Discourse

  > Sometimes support is more than just helping each other all day,
  >   hanging out with other people who use Ubuntu is also a good way to
  >   learn and make new friends. Sometimes you just want to kick back,
  >   relax, and talk about Ubuntu with the rest of the community.
  >
  > discourse.ubuntu.com is our watercooler, where you can discuss the
  >   latest news and developments in the Ubuntu world with other users and
  >   developers. If you’ve got an opinion on Ubuntu then this is the place
  >   to be heard!

---

For difference between Askubuntu & Ubuntuforums visit:-

- [What is the difference between Ubuntuforums and Askubuntu?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1351/256099)
- [Why is this site better than the Ubuntu Forums?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/234/256099)
- [content flow between Ask Ubuntu, Ubuntuforums, Ubuntu Wikis](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5456/256099)

Comment: I think Launchpad is also the place where a dev is most likely to answer. Further, Launchpad questions can be converted to bug reports and vice versa.

Comment: @muru I provided **visit** link for each which contains sufficient information.

Comment: indeed you have. I'm commenting about the feature that makes LP stand out, at least to me. What's the point of posting this QA here, if I have to go to look at each in another site anyway?

Comment: @muru for finding help with the help of **community-support system**

Comment: I hope that is some use of sarcasm. I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is the best place for inexperienced users, followed closely by ubuntuforums.  The others are more advanced.

Askubuntu is good because answers are voted on and users are ranked.  Ubuntuforums is also very good but there's no vetting.  There is a lot of good advice and also a lot of bad advice.  And how are noobs supposed to tell the difference?

You can't really tell if a forum users is reliable from their number of posts.  I've seen people with well over 1000 posts that don't really particularly know what they're talking about.  And others with 10 who were clearly pretty expert.

Biggest hint IMO: whatever it is ask your question clearly.  Learn how to display your hardware devices' make/model.  Saying it's some model with a 1.9GHz cpu doesn't help much.

It also helps a lot if you can say what you were doing when you had problems.  This isn't easy sometimes.  You may have to learn how to find log files.

This is just like getting anything fixed.  If you can explain what's wrong in understandable language it's going to be easier to fix.